Autometrics+Python+Telemetrics
I just start using autometrics but I could not send any metrics from this simple program
https://github.com/autometrics-dev/autometrics-py/blob/main/examples/docs-example.py
this is my init configuration
exporter = {
    "type": "otlp-proto-http",
    "address": "http://0.0.0.0:4317/",
    "insecure": True,  # Enabled for http transport
}
init(tracker="opentelemetry", service_name="TEST-SERVICE", exporter=exporter)


Any idea how to run autometrics with python an opentelemetry ?
BTW i'm using Signoz to visualize the metrics.
I tested it, an it is working with he command
telemetrygen traces --traces 1 --otlp-endpoint 0.0.0.0:4317 --otlp-insecure
Any help will be appreciated

my first suggestion would be to try using port 4318, as that is the default for otlp-http. (4317 is the default for grpc)
also this example might be a better starting point:
https://github.com/autometrics-dev/autometrics-py/blob/3b0e10c6975937ced1c1a7056aa8e8cbdecb9b20/examples/export_metrics/otlp-http.py
